# Синхронизация времени

Tags: php

На сервере (под debian) стоит правильное время, настроена синхронизация, т.е. вывод команды date правильный, в то время как команда time() php выдает рассинхронизацию на 4 часа, не смотря на то, что в php.ini временная зона не указана (т.е. по идее должна использоваться системная временная зона), как исправить?

ЗЫ: до этого синхронизировал системное время с помощью ntp

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое, но я не заморачивался, просто прописал

```
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions; http://php.net/date.timezonedate.timezone = Asia/Yekaterinburg
```

Comment: даже когда я принудительно указываю вот эту вот переменную, php дает рассинхронизацию в 4 часа

Comment: Решилось через date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow')ЗЫ: на самом деле не совсем понятно что конкретно привело к тому, что php стал показывать правильное время, ибо я много манипулировал связанными настройками системы, php